# How to delete row from table by row name?

Tags: javascript

I read that I can delete a row from a table by calling table.deleteRow(index) but I don't have the index of a row, I have the actual row object on a local variable.

What's the easiest way to delete the row by its row object or name?

```
 function DeleteRow(rowID) {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var row = document.getElementById(rowID);

    // is there a table.deleteRowByObject(rowID) ??
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 2):

With JQuery:
    $(row).remove();

This should do it without JQuery:
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);

Answer (score 1):

Three ways:

- `table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex)`
- `row.remove()` (not well supported)
- `row.parentNode.removeChild(row)`. You won't be able to use `table.removeChild` because the parent is a [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) actually.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, can try something like

```
$('tr[name=rowname]').remove();
```

In plain JavaScript, this might work (not tested)

```
var idx = myRowObject.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("myTableId").deleteRow(idx);
```

Comment: But OP doesn't use jQuery…